# Near stalling shake at slow turns

Tags: transmission, stall, skoda, octavia

It is 2012 Skoda Octavia 1.4 TSI DSG7. When slow turns (i.e. u turns), car starts to shake like it is about to stall. The rpm is low but stable, engine sounds under-rpm, tiny vibration on steering wheel and all effects are intensified if you push the throttle more and more. So is it transmission/clutch problem, front group of steering/suspension unit or something else?

Comment: Is this a manual transmission car?  Is the clutch pedal down our up when you are experiencing this problem?

Comment: Not it is no-clutch-pedal & full auto transmission.

Comment: If you move the same speed but without turning, do you experience the problem?

Comment: Nope, only at turns and straight drives go smooth.

Comment: Sounds like the vibration could possible be coming from the power steering system.

Comment: Could it be worthwhile to check the steering hydraulic oil level as a preemptive action?

Comment: Definitely first thing to check.  Also check the belt tension, it could be slipping.

Comment: Does it happen if you are going left or right? When you go around this sharp corner, do you run the steering wheel all the way to one side (until you can turn it no further)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are turning the wheel all the way (left or right) until it stops, this is called cramping the steering. What happens is, when you get it all the way over to one side and hold it there, the rack and pinion is telling the hydraulic fluid to continue to push the steering over to that side, but the steering mechanism cannot do it because it cannot go any further. This sends pressure waves back through the hydraulic system which causes the pump to stall momentarily. When this happens, the pump slows the engine down.

To counter this ... don't cramp your steering. Run steering wheel right *up to* the end of where it can turn the wheels and don't go any further. You will not get the wheels to turn in that direction any further anyway, so you are causing yourself an issue which doesn't need to happen.

Comment: Yes I am turning the wheel to the most end. As I said it happens in a u turn where the road is narrow and perimeter is wide. So I go till the end of steering to complete the turn. I haven't verified your diagnosis yet but I can tell you it does not happen during small manoeuvres like parking.

Comment: Good points. Do you think it could be a constant velocity joint that's beginning to fail Paulster2? I think they work pretty hard when turning fully (and even harder when accelerating).

Comment: @Allman - No, I don't suspect a CVJ at all. Completely different symptoms (clicking in the front end while turning ... binding doesn't regularly occur).

Answer (score 1):

From the symptoms, I think the power steering belt will be slipping under the load at low engine speed.